# PHP regex class Intervals

Tags: php, regex

I learn PHP regex
Normally the following code should show me "FALSE" on the screen
But it shows me "TRUE"
Can you tell me why?
Thank you

```
<?php

if (preg_match("#[^a-z]#", "la nuit, tous les chats sont gras")) 
{echo 'TRUE';}
else 
{echo 'FALSE';} 

?>
```

Comment: Why do you expect false?

Comment: Spaces and commas are non alpha characters. Use anchors for a full match, or http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-lower.php.

Comment: also, it's "la nuit, tous les chats sont gr*i*s"

Answer (score 2):

A `preg_match` when used with an unanchored regex searches for partial matches.

If you want to make sure the whole string consists of chars other than lowercase ASCII letters, use

```
if (preg_match("#^[^a-z]*$#", "la nuit, tous les chats sont gras")) 
{echo 'TRUE';}
else 
{echo 'FALSE';}
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/3TtyAB)

**Details**:

- `^` - string start
- `[^a-z]*`  - zero or more chars other than lowercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string (or maybe `\z` would be better here to match the very end of the string).

Comment: See also [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UiMZN4/1).

Answer (score 0):

Let me split this for you:

- `[]` A Group
- `^` Inside A Group means "not in", all definitions in the group means the opposite of it
- `a-z` All Letters from small a to small z

At the end you have found all spaces and the comma.

Answer (score 0):

In your regular expression you are try to find the first non-alphabetic character and in your subject string this symbols are present. Check it:

```
preg_match_all("#^[^a-z]*$#", "la nuit, tous les chats sont gras", $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Result

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string ' ' (length=1)
      1 => string ',' (length=1)
      2 => string ' ' (length=1)
      3 => string ' ' (length=1)
      4 => string ' ' (length=1)
      5 => string ' ' (length=1)
      6 => string ' ' (length=1)
```